# What foreground selection algorithm does GIMP use?

Tags: image-processing, gimp

Title says it all.

I would have thought that there would be a reference to the algorithm in the documentation, but there doesn't seem to be one.

I could probably find out from the source, but ... it's a huuuuge code base :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Uniform Color Clustering

It does not matter how huge a code base is. It is a matter of seconds to find all files that contain the words foreground and select. A few minutes later you find:

https://github.com/GNOME/gimp/blob/5d79fba8238a27b8691556489898d33b3fa0dda0/libgimp/gimpdrawable_pdb.c#L1065

```
 * Extract the foreground of a drawable using a given trimap.
 *
 * Image Segmentation by Uniform Color Clustering, see
 * https://www.inf.fu-berlin.de/inst/pubs/tr-b-05-07.pdf
```

> **Abstract**. The following article presents an approach for interactive
>   foreground extraction in still images. The presented approach has been
>   derived from color signatures, a technique originated from image
>   retrieval. The article explains the algorithm and presents some
>   benchmark results to show the improvements in speed and accuracy
>   compared to state-ofthe-art solutions. The article also describes how
>   the algorithm can easily be adapted for video segmentation.

https://www.inf.fu-berlin.de/inst/pubs/tr-b-05-07.pdf

Comment: To be honest I didn't even find the github code base... I clicked through several pages that document "Gimp from Source" and landed on some GitLab instance. There entering foreground selection yielded thousand irrelevant results and I tried to find the algorithm from "tools_commands.c" after which I just gave up... So thanks for the answer!